# Sitecore WFFM validation not kicking in

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

In Sitecore 8.0 I created a new WFFM validation to test for file upload size. I did that by creating a new class inherited from FormCustomValidator and then I created the matching Sitecore validator and I added the new validator to a custom file upload field (duplicate of Sitecore file upload field). Unfortunately, the validation is not kicking in when place the new field on a form. 
What did I miss?

```cs
public class FileSizeValidator : FormCustomValidator
    {

        public int MaxFileSize
        {
            get
            {
                Log.Info("MaxFileSize get", this);
                int maxSize;
                if (int.TryParse(classAttributes["MaxFileSize"], out maxSize))
                {
                    return maxSize;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            set
            {
                Log.Info("MaxFileSize set", this);
                base.classAttributes["MaxFileSize"] = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public FileSizeValidator()
        {
            Log.Info("FileSizeValidator", this);
            ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(OnValidate);
        }

        private void OnValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("OnServerValidate", this);
            FileUpload fileUpload = FindControl(ControlToValidate) as FileUpload;
            if (!fileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
            args.IsValid = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= MaxFileSize;
        }

        protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControlToValidate))
                    return base.EvaluateIsValid();
                else
                    return true;
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Error Message";
            this.Text = "Text";
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this one: https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/06/09/sitecore-webforms-for-marketers-mime-type-sniffer-custom-field-validator/

Comment: I did and it didn't work. I think the problem is because we're using MVC forms. Have anyone done it with MVC?